# Trying to inject a service into a component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am new to angular2
- I am trying to inject a service into a component.
- In the below stackblitz I have a simple component and a simple service.
- Can you guys tell me how to do it.
- So that in future I can do it myself.
- Providing my code below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj8xcu?file=app/example.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SwPeopleService {
    people$ = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
      .map((res:any) => res.results);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 
}
```

Comment: Read the tutorial so you can do it yourself now: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I updated your code in stackblitz but still, I am facing the errors. Can you update in my stackblitz providing it below?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqpamw?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Come on dude, the stackblitz error message clearly spells out the  error: you should remove the `.ts` extension from your import.

Comment: There's a line between asking a question and asking people to do your work for you. You're crossing that line with every comment you make. The tutorial I linked in my first comment spells it out step by step, yet you have to have someone do it for you "so you can learn". When someone finally ends up doing it, you fail to write a correct `import` statement, and don't even bother to look at the error message. Again someone has to step in to fix it for you "so you can learn". This is not how you learn.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hey in the console I checked for the error but I don't see anything...can you explain in detail...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your service under providers inside app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FontcolorDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers : [SwPeopleService]
})
```

and then inject in your component as,

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor(private peopleservice: SwPeopleService) {} 
}
```

also you need to import **HttpClientModule** under imports

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FontcolorDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers : [SwPeopleService]
})
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ludszf?file=app/app.module.ts)**

Comment: hey I updated your code it didnt work...its so confusing...can you update in stackblitz...so that i can learn

Comment: we are not coding service

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I updated your code in stackblitz but still, I am facing the errors. Can you update in my stackblitz providing it below?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqpamw?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: @arkr Added a working demo, mark as answer if it helped

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me why your adding services in providers, why its included in the constructor and why we should include HttpClientModule....this will help me in some more better understanding

Comment: You need to add all the services under providers and you need to use httpclient since you are making http call. please mark the answer

Comment: so what does providers does?

Comment: well you should read the docs before asking a question https://angular.io/guide/providers